# Does Azure APIM support GraphQL?

Tags: azure, graphql, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-management

We have microservices setup with Azure APIM as gateway and routers to all the services in the back. Is there anyway I can introduce GrpahQl before APIM or within APIM ?

Comment: With limitations, you can serve it [over HTTP](https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/) with Azure API Management. However, the full support [isn't on the roadmap](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management/suggestions/32113882-graphql-introspective-support-within-api-managemen).

Comment: It's supported as of Nov 2021. See [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69813080/7724443)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your immediate question, there is no support for GraphQL via Azure APIM to date.

Its one of these feature this has been upvoted by me and many others on Azure uservoice @ [GraphQL introspective support within API Management](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management/suggestions/32113882-graphql-introspective-support-within-api-managemen) / feedback forums.

Also see [What additional services should Azure provide?](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/170024-additional-services/suggestions/35390665-graphql-based-api-service)

## UPDATED MAY 2022

Preview Features

Synthetic GraphQL allows you to easily create a GraphQL API based on your existing HTTP (SOAP or REST) APIs. This allows you to quickly upgrade your API to support modern client application development without affecting your existing infrastructure.

With this availability, you can:

Change your existing APIs into GraphQL to support modern client application development. Build a GraphQL API from existing SOAP, REST, and other HTTP APIs.

Augment your existing GraphQL API with third party APIs such as Microsoft Graph, Dynamics, Shopify, and Zendesk.

Announcement: https://azure.microsoft.com/services/api-management/#overview

Documentation: https://azure.microsoft.com/updates/public-preview-synthetic-graphql/

Comment: what is the issue if we define a post graphql endpoint in APIM ?  We can manually configure this in APIM as a workaround.  What do we loose in this approach ?

Comment: I tried doing this and at startup gateway failed with auth error . I believe the reason behind this is that at startup gateway tries load services/subgraphs which is apparently deployed behind APIM and APIM send auth error because gateway cannot send JWT tokens at startup

Comment: GraphQL support in APIM is in public preview now: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/public-preview-graphql-passthrough-support-in-azure-api-management/

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your backend APIs are written to support GraphQL, importing GraphQL APIs is now available (in preview, at the time of writing this response) by Azure API Management: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/graphql-api

GraphQL validation policies are also available (in preview): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/graphql-validation-policies

Comment: GraphQL support has recently been added to APIM.

Comment: does it support GraphQL subscriptions as well?