# GraphQL to Swagger (Azure APIM)

Tags: graphql

I am new to graphql and wanted to know how to creating a swagger out of graphql endpoint. Will any features of GraphQL be restricted if I use a swagger?  I need the swagger to host my api(s) behind Azure APIM.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59153464/6124657

Comment: The product team has told me to check if I could create swagger from graphql and then upload them in apim

Comment: ask them for an example :D - there is ONE ENDPOINT (url) in graphql ... tons of swagger to graphql converters/tools ... zero for opposite direction ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Azure APIM support GraphQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59153464/does-azure-apim-support-graphql)